Skorokhod-like construction for sequences of random probability measures
Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random vectors with distribution $P$ on $[0,1]^d$.
Let $D \equiv D([0,1]^d)$ be the multivariate Skorokhod space, equiped with a metric $d$ that makes it Polish. Let $\mathscr{D}$ be the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Finally, let $\mu_n(\,\cdot\,; \,\cdot\,)$ be such that for each $n=1, 2, \dotsc$ :

and $P^{(n)}$-almost every sequence $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$, the map $B \mapsto \mu_n(B;x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a probability measure on $(D, \mathscr{D})$
and set $B \in \mathscr{D}$, the map $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)\mapsto \mu_n(B; x_1, \ldots,x_n)$ is measurable.

QUESTION Suppose that, for a metric $\rho$ metrizing weak convergence and the probability measure $\mu_0$ of a $P$-Brownian bridge, we have
$$
\rho(\mu_n(\,\cdot\,; X_1, \ldots, X_n), \mu_0) \to 0, \quad \text{$P^{(\infty)}$-a.s.}
$$
Is there something similar to a Skorokhod's construction under which, for any $\epsilon>0$, almost surely as $n \to \infty$
$$
\mu_n^*(\{f \in D : \, d(f,\mathbb{B})> \epsilon\}; \, X_1^*, \dotsc, X_n^*) \to 0, 
$$
where $\mu_n^*(\cdot;X_1^*, \dotsc, X_n^*)\overset{d}{=} \mu_n(\cdot;X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$ and $(X_i^*)\overset{d}{=}(X_i)$ and where $\mathbb{B}\equiv \mathbb{B}(\,\cdot\,; X_1^*, \dotsc, X_n^*)\sim \mu_0$ for $n=1,2,\dotsc$?

In general, there are different transliteration conventions, but "Skorokhod" rather than "Skohorod" seems to be the accepted one here. I edited accordingly.

If I understand your question right, then in general no and likely never.
Let $\mu_n(\cdot \,\,;X_1, \dots, X_n) := \mu_0(\cdot)$. Then $\rho(\mu_n(\cdot \,\,;X_1, \dots, X_n), \mu_0) = 0$.
But for any potential Skorokhod-like construction $\mu^*_n(\cdot \,\,;X_1, \dots, X_n) := \mu_0(\cdot)$ almost surely, so
$$\mu_n^*(\{f \in D : \, d(f,\mathbb{B})> \epsilon\}; \, X_1^*, \ldots, X_n^*) = \mu_0(\{f \in D : \, d(f,\mathbb{B})> \epsilon\}) > 0$$ almost surely.
